# is there any way to set scrollbar position to left in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have UIText view . By default when text get overflown then it has scroll bar and it shows scroll bar indicator at right hand . But while working with arabic language ideally I want it left side of UITextView . Is there any way to do it in iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Autolayout:

> **From apple documentation:** Cocoa Auto Layout allows individual views to declare their own preferred size, which means you don’t have
>   to specify new layout if the label’s text changes—for example, because
>   of localization, as illustrated in the right window. You don’t even
>   have to specify new layout for languages like Hebrew and Arabic in
>   which the left to right ordering of elements themselves should
>   generally be reversed.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Comment: I'm with Nikos on this in that Autolayout was designed with your exact situation in mind. Otherwise your options are to pass in some negative values to the setScrollIndicatorInsets property of you UIScrollView inherited class.